# how to put multiple AND's with variables in a php/mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

Tried lots of different things to make it work, couldnt find the answer on the internet if its even possible to put 2 AND's with variable into 1 query. Hopefully someone can help me with this one.

Im trying to make a rating system with 1-5 points. There is a rating row in the database and the value should be put in front of the
/5

First try:

```
    $query2 = "SELECT rating, gebruikersnaam, Foto.fotoid FROM rating, Foto WHERE rating.fotoid = Foto.fotoid AND Foto.fotoid = '".$id."'" AND gebruikersnaam "'".$gebruikersnaam."'";
```

Edited version

```
"SELECT rating, gebruikersnaam, Foto.fotoid
 FROM rating
 INNER JOIN Foto ON rating.fotoid = Foto.fotoid
 WHERE rating.fotoid = Foto.fotoid AND Foto.fotoid = '" . $id . "' AND gebruikersnaam '" . $gebruikersnaam . "'";
 $result2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $query2);

var_dump($result2);
echo $query2;

$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
echo "<h2>".$row2['gebruikersnaam']."</h2>";
echo "<h2>".$row2['rating']."/5</h2>";
```

**var_dump(result2); echoes:**

bool(false)

**query2 echoes:**

SELECT rating, gebruikersnaam, Foto.fotoid FROM rating INNER JOIN Foto ON rating.fotoid = Foto.fotoid WHERE rating.fotoid = Foto.fotoid AND Foto.fotoid = '54' AND gebruikersnaam 'Kees'

```
echo "<h2>".$row2['rating']."/5</h2>";
```

The code doesnt seem to get the ['rating'] anymore?

Comment: It seems that you are joining two tables?

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Do you have an error?

Comment: It seems your query missing an "="? should it be "AND gebruikersnaam = 'Kees'"

Comment: tried with and without the '=', without does give me the right gebruikersnaam. The problem is that it doesnt echo 'rating'

Answer (score 1):

This should work! you put to much `""` in the string! Also do a JOIN to the second table.

```
 $query2 = "SELECT rating, gebruikersnaam, Foto.fotoid
            FROM rating
            INNER JOIN Foto ON rating.fotoid = Foto.fotoid
            WHERE rating.fotoid = Foto.fotoid AND Foto.fotoid = '" . $id . "' AND gebruikersnaam '" . $gebruikersnaam . "'";
```

Comment: i tried to make it work with your query, your query seems to work but my echo doesnt work with getting the rating out of my database. Btw. thanks for the fast response!

Comment: @Kumar But you can output `gebruikersnaam` ?

Comment: gebruikersnaam does give the name of the session user. So that seems to work fine. 

echo "<h2>".$row2['rating']."/5</h2>"; doesnt echo rating, where rating is a row in Mysql database with numbers from 1-5.